# manage.py runserver fails after putting custom app in middleware

Tags: python, django

Im following a guide on youtube to work with django. Unfortunately this guide is made for pre 2.0 django. 
So the challenge is to create a app called "posts" that can be accessed by localhost/posts.

After creating the folder 'posts' and adding it to settings.py MIDDLEWARE like this:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
'posts',
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
```

]

`python manage.py runserver` fails

When commenting 'posts' out `runserver` succedes.

The problem is that Im so new to all of this that I don't even know what to search for.

Comment: put your middle ware as the last item on the list and try again, if it doesn't work put a full stack trace.

Comment: I didn't realise Django was now in V2. However, isn't `posts` supposed to be added to `INSTALLED_APPS`, not `MIDDLEWARE`?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to add `'posts'` to `MIDDLEWARE` in *any* version of Django. Are you sure the tutorial didn't ask you to add it to `INSTALLED_APPS` instead?

Comment: It would help a lot if you posted the exact error message that you get from runserver, instead of generically telling us "it fails".

Comment: @Alasdair I rewatched it. Yes he did. I'm a little bit embarrassed right now ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding 'post' in INSTALLED_APPS inside settings.py like this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'post',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
```

]

and delete it from middleware.
You have to "install" all the apps you make

Comment: Yes, this was my problem. Thanks :)